# Best way to expand $(2+x-x^2)^6$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

[image]

I've completed part $(a)$ and gotten:

$64+192y+240y^2+160y^3+...$

Using intuition I substituted $x-x^2$ for $y$ and started listing the values for :

$y, y^2 $ and $y^3,$ in terms of $x$.

$y=(x-x^2)\\y^2=(x-x^2)^2 = x^2-2x^3+x^4;\\y^3 = (x-x^2)^3 = (x-x^2)(x^2-2x^3+x^4) = \;...$

Everything became complicated before I had even started to substitute these new-found values back into the polynomial devised from part $(a)$; for a 3 - *out of 75* - mark question this seems extremely over-complicated. Am I doing it inefficiently / incorrectly; is there a pre-defined or easier method; or is it simple expansion and substitution that I'm too lazy to complete?

Comment: Good intuition: You were almost there! Use $y^3= x^3 + ...$ and ignore any higher powers of $y$.

Comment: Is the method I proposed really the correct way to combat this question?

Comment: It's the "3 Marks" that's throwing me off, all of that work for only 3 is very surprising.

Comment: I personally don't see any other way. Just replace in the new answer $y=x-x^2$, $y^2 =x^2-2x^3$ and $y^3 = x^3$. All the other terms in $x$ will have higher powers.

Comment: I guess that would work, I'll remember next time to simply ignore powers over the specified boundary - immediately; simplifies the problem greatly.

Comment: It's computation only basically, it's a little tedious but not too bad. A thing to keep in mind is that when you expand something like $(x+x^2+...+x^n)^k$ the lowest power will always be $x^k$. You can also generalise this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here  is another proposal about how to calculate example 4b). We start with

> **Some considerations**
>
> - At first it was a good idea from OP to start with 4a.). Due to the similarity of the somewhat simpler expression
>     \begin{align*}
>   (2+y)^6=64+192y+240y^2+160y^3+\cdots\tag{1}
>   \end{align*}
>     compared with $(2+x-x^2)^6$ we can use the substitution
>     $$y:=x-x^2$$
>     and the result is
>     \begin{align*}
>   (2+x-x^2)^2=64+192(x-x^2)+240(x-x^2)^2+160(x-x^2)^3+\cdots\tag{2}
>   \end{align*}
> - Since we only need an expansion with powers up to $x^3$ we don't need any terms $(x-x^2)^n$ with $n>3$.
> - We also recall the *[binomial formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)* $(a+b)^n$ for $n=2,3$
>     \begin{align*}
>   (a+b)^2&=a^2+2ab+b^2\\
>   (a+b)^3&=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3
>   \end{align*}
>     which we will use when expanding (2).

Now we have all the ingredients to effectively expand (2) up to powers of $x^3$.

> **The calculation**
>
> We obtain from (1) with the substitution: $y:= x-x^2$
>   \begin{align*}
> (2+x-x^2)^2&=64+192(x-x^2)+240(x-x^2)^2+160(x-x^2)^3+\cdots\\
> &=64+192(x-x^2)+240(x^2-2x^3)+160(x^3)+\cdots\tag{3}\\
> &=64+192x+(-192+240)x^2+(240\cdot(-2)+160)x^3+\cdots\tag{4}\\
> &=64+192x+48x^2-320x^3+\cdots
> \end{align*}
>   and we're done here.

*Comment:*

- In (3) we expand the binomial formula up to third powers of $x$; everything else is put to $+\cdots$.
- In (4) we collect terms with equal powers.

Answer (score 1):

You have everything you need.

Just multiply out $y^3$ as you have it and you'll get something with $x^3$ and higher powers of $x$.

Then, note that $y^4$ has terms of $x^4$ and higher, so they're all in the dot-dot-dot, which is Not Your Problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would say

$((x+2)(x-1))^6 = (x+2)^6(x-1)^6\\
(64 + 192x + 240x^2 + 160x^3 ...)(1 - 6x + 15x^2 - 20x^3 ...)$

I don't care about any powers bigger than 3

$64 + (64(-6) + 192)x + (64*15+192(-6) + 240)x^2 + (64(-20)+ 192*15 + 240*(-6) + 160)x^3...\\
64 - 192 x + 48 x^2 + 320x^3...$